# Remove images from RSS feed

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, rss

I'm building a site in WordPress in which I need to pull in an RSS feed from another site to display on a page. I've pulled it in, limited the number of items successfully. I've figured out how to truncate the description to limit it to a certain number of characters.

However if the post has images in the truncation gets messed up. I've tried many different ways of stripping out the 'img' tag and I haven't been successful yet. Any guidance on the correct way to do this would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code for the blog section:

```
<?php 
//fetch rss feed 
$rss = fetch_feed('http://solar.greenstreetsolarpower.com/blog/rss.xml');
$rss->strip_htmltags('img');
// Checks that the object is created correctly
if ( ! is_wp_error( $rss ) ) : 
    //figure total items and limit to 3
    $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity( 3 ); 
    //build array of all times starting with first element
    $rss_items = $rss->get_items( 0, $maxitems );
else: 
    echo 'RSS Feed is broken';
endif; ?>

<section>
    <div class="blog-header">
        <h2>Power Blog</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <?php foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : 
        $excerpt = $item->get_description();
        $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, 120);
        ?>
        <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns blog-excerpt">
            <h3><?php echo esc_html( $item->get_title() ); ?></h3>
            <p style="font-size: .8em !important;"><?php echo $excerpt; ?></p>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $item->get_permalink() ); ?>" title="<?php printf( __( 'Posted %s', 'my-text-domain' ), $item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a') ); ?>">Continue</a>
        </div>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>

</section>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

See: http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie/strip_htmltags#description for reference to the method you are using.

strip_htmltags method expects the tags to be passed in an array and may not know how to handle an argument that is a single string.

Changing line 4 to `$rss->strip_htmltags($tags = array('img'));` should work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I made this change and I'm still not getting the correct result. When I do this it strips out the entire description, not just the 'img' tag. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: RSS comes in quite a few variants and none of them work the same way. You may want to validate the RSS feed to make sure this isn't causing problems. Generally speaking, if a RSS feed doesn't conform to the standard the parser expects, the parser will just die.

Comment: It's also possible that the SimplePie parser's strip_htmltags method will invalidate the description if it finds ANY violating tags. You could try using the encode_instead_of_strip method. http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie/encode_instead_of_strip